# Close an app from another app

Tags: android

I have application A and application B.

I launch B with an intent from A in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.applicationB", "com.applicationB.MainActivity");
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME,"name");
startActivity(intent);
```

When the user closes application A I want application B to close too. App B has JNI and uses `exec()` command.

I've tried [`android:sharedUserId`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) but I got this error when app A tries to launch B with the code above:

```
Error running exec(). Command: [....] Working Directory: null Environment: (not null, it shows all the environment.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

you must use android IPC mechanisms like broadcast receiver

when application A closes it should send a broadcast and application B should register for a broadcast receiver to capture broadcasts from application A

see the documents for more info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 1):

If both applications are programmed by yourself, you could consider to add a `BroadcastReceiver` in app B, that takes care, that all activities get closed. Before app A closes, call that receiver and it's done.

If you are not sure which activity is shown, you could extend the Activity class with a `BroadcastReceiver`, so that all activities get notified.

If app B is not programmed by you, you could use `killbackgroundProcesses()`, e.g.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(myProcessId);
```

... however, this works only if app B is in fact in background. Additionally this is not the best option to close an app 'cause you do not know what the app is currently doing.

**Edit**: found my favorite example on that topic :-) check http://www.hrupin.com/2011/10/how-to-finish-all-activities-in-your-android-application-through-simple-call - it shows how to close all activities from within the app. However, it's not a big step doing this from another one ...